# Mongo shell 3.2 displays non-existing collection?

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB 3.2, mongo shell shows `result` collection but dropping and stats report the collection does not exist.

```
> show collections
cronHistory
logs
result 
system.indexes
system.profile

> db.result.stats()
{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "Collection [logs.result] not found." }

> db.result.drop()
false
```

If I insert into `result` collection, a new collection is created:

```
> db.result.insert({})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> show collections
cronHistory
logs
result
result 
system.indexes
system.profile
>
```

What is this ghost result collection shown in mongoshell?

Comment: I can't reproduce this.

Comment: There may be a hidden character in that collection's name. Can you edit your question to show the output of `db.getCollectionNames()`?

Comment: Yes, there is a space at the end of result. Removed it with db.runCommand( { drop: "result "}). Thanks alot!